# Troubles with WP after moving to another host

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I had moved WP from one hosting to another. I moved all files and database.
But now I have problems with opening my new website at http://camel-nekretnine.ba

This is what I got in error log:

```
[27-Feb-2015 14:30:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:30:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:30:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:30:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:31:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:33:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:33:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:34:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:34:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:37:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:37:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:40:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:40:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:41:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:41:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:41:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:41:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:41:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:41:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:43:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:43:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:45:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
[27-Feb-2015 14:45:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/camelnek/public_html//wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/camelnek/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpclef/includes/lib/utils.inc on line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to upload some files and that is reason why this error happens. I suggest to moderators to totally remove this post and I really need to apologize. Sorry...